# How to build a guided app walk through in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created the onboarding screen for new users but I want to go one step further.

I want to explain the concept of the app by making users perform certain interactions when a user opens the app for the first time.

I am looking for a library/methodology that might help me achieve this - to create a guided tour on first open, making him perform certain actions on widgets across multiple screens before the user can start interacting with the widgets on his own. Something similar to the Dinner Dash intro mentioned in this article - https://www.wyzowl.com/walkthrough-examples/

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you this plugin to make a wonderful onboarding : https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen

You can custom each page as you want !

good dev